# How to compare items among 3 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to add comparison among 3 lists. listB is compared to listA and then listA is compared to listC to create a new combined items.

```
listA = ['abcd755 - (45)', 'abcd754 - (32.12)', '3xas34a - (43.23)', '01shdsa - (0.01)']
listB = ['abcd754', '23xas34a', 'abcd755', '01shdsa']
listC = ['abcd755 - staff1', 'abcd754 - staff2', '3xas34a - demo1', '01shdsa - staff3', '23xas34a - demo2']

out = []

for b in listB:
    if any((c := a).startswith(b) for a in listA):
        out.append(c)

print(out)
```

Current Output: # comparing 2 list

```
['abcd754 - (32.12)', 'abcd755 - (45)', '01shdsa - (0.01)']
```

Output Needed: # a combination of data from amonglists

```
['abcd754 - (32.12) - staff2', 'abcd755 - (45) - staff1', '01shdsa - (0.01) - staff3']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your listA and listC are effectively key-value pairs, so you could convert them to dictionaries and then look up their values for the entries in listB:

```
dict_a = dict(n.split(" - ", maxsplit=1) for n in listA)
dict_c = dict(n.split(" - ", maxsplit=1) for n in listC)

for b in listB:
    if b in dict_a and b in dict_c:
        out.append(f"{b} - {dict_a[b]} - {dict_c[b]}")
```

```
>>> out
['abcd754 - (32.12) - staff2',
 'abcd755 - (45) - staff1',
 '01shdsa - (0.01) - staff3']
```

---

Edit: If you want everything where listA and listB have matching keys and don't actually need listB (Which acts as a filter here), you can bypass listB altogether:

```
for key in set(dict_a).intersection(dict_c):
    out.append(f"{key} - {dict_a[key]} - {dict_c[key]}")
```

```
>>> out
['3xas34a - (43.23) - demo1',  # notice that this will then also be catched
 'abcd754 - (32.12) - staff2',
 '01shdsa - (0.01) - staff3',
 'abcd755 - (45) - staff1']
```

Also notice that with this approach, the order of elements might be different, though you can get around that if really needed.

Comment: would it be possble to just directly compare listC to listA and still produce the same output?

Comment: @rbutrnz Yes, but then You'll also generate the Value `'3xas34a - (43.23) - demo1'`  in `out`. I can make an edit outlining that

Comment: could please so that I can compare and see the difference?

Comment: Edit is made @rbutrnz

Comment: So the problem of the second approach is that it will also catch even if its not a match.

Comment: The keys in listA and listC do match, but the demo match is not part of listB. Depending on what exactly listB means to you, if listA and listC are basically lookup-tables, you might not want to get every information you have every time, but just for the values you got in listB. But if you generated listB only to have a common element to join listA and listC, then you might not need it, as that would also save you the possibility of typos, if the additional leading 2 in `23xas34a` happened by accident.

Comment: one last thing, my listC is in this format `listC = ['staff1 - abcd755', 'staff2 - abcd754', 'demo1 - 3xas34a ', 'staff3 - 01shdsa', 'demo2 - 23xas34a']`, running the script creates no output.

Comment: When the keys and values are the other way around, then you can reverse the split: `dict_c = dict(n.split(" - ", maxsplit=1)[::-1] for n in listC)`

Answer (score 1):

```
# your code goes here
listA = ['abcd755 - (45)', 'abcd754 - (32.12)', '3xas34a - (43.23)', '01shdsa - (0.01)']
listB = ['abcd754', '23xas34a', 'abcd755', '01shdsa']
listC = ['abcd755 - staff1', 'abcd754 - staff2', '3xas34a - demo1', '01shdsa - staff3', '23xas34a - demo2']
from collections import defaultdict as dd

out = dd(list)
for i in listA:
    a, b = i.split(' - ')
    out[a].append(b)

for i in listC:
    a, b = i.split(' - ')
    if a in out:
        out[a].append(b)

result = []
for i in listB:
    if i in out:
        result.append(' - '.join([i, *out[i]]))
print(result)
```

## output

```
['abcd754 - (32.12) - staff2', 'abcd755 - (45) - staff1', '01shdsa - (0.01) - staff3']
```